# How can I use input field name in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a web app using ruby on rails, but facing some issue on input field name. I need use manual input field name for use `Jquery`.

by default rails input field type:

```
<input id="post_title" class="form-control" type="text" name="post[title]" placeholder="Post Title">
```

Thanks

Comment: How does your ERB tag look at the moment? What `name` do your need? Why does your jQuery code need a special named tag?

Comment: For example I need client side instat form validation for my form that's time need input field name, if I use name manually then validation ok but data nut submitting

Answer (score -1):

You can use text_field_tag.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag

Please read official ror documentation.

Example

text_field_tag 'your custom name'

or even

text_field_tag :your_custom_name

Comment: You do not understood my question

Comment: You can add custom class with :class => 'your custom class here.'